# Python subprocess arguments

Tags: python, subprocess, command-line-arguments

For example I am using `ffplay` and want to run this command `-bufsize[:stream_specifier] integer (output,audio,video)`

At the moment I have this:

```
subprocess.call(["ffplay", "-vn", "-nodisp","-bufsize 4096", "%s" % url])
```

But this says it is invalid.

Comment: `-bufsize` and `4096` should be separated

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As JBernardo mentioned in a comment, separate the `"-bufsize 4096"` argument into two, `"-bufsize", "4096"`. Each argument needs to be separated when `subprocess.call` is used with `shell=False` (the default). You can also specify `shell=True` and give the whole command as a single string, but this is not recommended due to potential security vulnerabilities.

You should not need to use string formatting where you have `"%s" % url`. If `url` is a string, pass it directly, otherwise call `str(url)` to get a string representation.

Answer (score 7):

This is the way to go:

```
url = 'http://www.whatever.com'
cmd = 'ffplay -vn -nodisp -bufsize 4096 '.split()
subprocess.call(cmd + [str(url)], shell=False)
```

Comment: What if `url` contains spaces?

Comment: That was my point, that this is not "the way to go" because it is rather fragile.

Comment: I think it would be fragile if one url out of 5 was containing spaces. Don't you think?

Comment: It's fragile because it breaks on some valid input. If only one URL in 100 contains spaces, it makes the problem that much harder to debug when it occurs. There's an easy way to avoid this bug, too; see my solution.

Comment: You are right. Can you please modify my code so that it includes your solution.

Comment: I've edited  your answer with my solution, though it is still in the peer-review queue currently.

Comment: "bukzor", why don't you tell us why?

Comment: This works for this particular set of arguments, but if any of the arguments *other* than the url contains a space (and is quoted), then it will still break. Using `shlex.split` deals with these kinds of corner cases.

Comment: I really like the use of .split() in this example.  It makes it super easy to take a normal command-line, paste it into a variable and split it for consumption by subprocess.

Answer (score 5):

While using `shlex.split()` is overkill for your use case, many of the comments seem to be asking about the use of spaces in parameters in cases where a CLI allows you to pass in quoted strings containing spaces (i.e. `git commit -m "Commit message here"`).

Here is a quick python function that can be used to run commands including parameters with spaces:

```
import shlex, subprocess

def run_command( command ):
    subprocess.call(shlex.split(command))
```