# Permission denied to run shell script by subprocess.call

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

I wrote a shell script using python and it successfully run by command `bash download_R1.sh` on my terminal.

I wanted to test if subprocess can do the same thing in python because I would like to integrate a pipeline in python script. Here is the subprocess part of my code:

```
downR1 = subprocess.call('./download_R1.sh')
```

It failed to run the script with following error message:

```
Error message:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './download_R1.sh'
```

Someone suggested using `chmod +x` to obtain authenitification of that script. But `bash down.sh` is working. I don't know which part goes wrong.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the normal way the shell behaves.

You can not directly run a program or script if it not has execution privileges (`+x`)

But, you can instruct other program `bash`, `python` or whatever to run a file even if not has `+x`

**foo.sh**

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# If a parameter is received in the command $1, assign it to $NAME
# if not use the default "World"
NAME="${1:-World}"

echo "Hello ${NAME}"
```

**foo.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print "Hello World"
```

```
$ bash foo.sh
Hello World

$ bash foo.sh Person
Hello Person

$ ./foo.sh
bash: ./foo.sh: Permission denied

$ python foo.py
Hello World


$ ./foo.py
bash: ./foo.sh: Permission denied

$ chmod +x foo.sh foo.py

$ ./foo.sh
Hello World
$ ./foo.py
Hello World
```

In your case, if you want to run the program with `subprocess` but not giving execution privileges to the file you must use:

```py
subprocess.run(["bash", "download_R1.sh"])
```

If you need to pass arguments to the script just add more items to the list:

```py
subprocess.run(["bash", "download_R1.sh", "argument1"])
```

There are several questions about using subprocess an arguments [like  this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679936/python-subprocess-arguments).

If you prefer write you command in only one string be advised that use `shell=True` is [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3172488/930271). But you can use something like:

```py
subprocess.run("bash download_R1.sh argument1".split())
```

Comment: OP's script is a `bash` script, so they need `subprocess.run(["bash", "download_R1.sh"])`. ... I think.

Comment: Oh, I understand now! Thank you. You are correct except `subprocess.run(["python", "download_R1.sh"])` should be `subprocess.run(["bash", "download_R1.sh"])`. May I ask one more question? In document describing `subprocess.run(args)`, it said that `The arguments used to launch the process. This may be a list or a string`. `bash download_R1.sh` is a string. But what about list? Does it mean subprocess can consecutively run shell scripts following the list, e.g. `('bash 1.sh' , 'bash 2.sh', 'bash 3.sh')`?

Comment: After a few test, I know how args input should look like. Args receive a list composed of a seperated command, like ['bash', '1.sh'], or a string 'bash 1.sh' but only with `shell=True` to enable it, otherwise it will report FileNotFound error. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes you can pass one long string as the full command with `shell=True` but it's not recommend https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess use `long_string.split()` with `shell=False` if needed