# In Spotfire, how to write a Python script that calls multiple R scripts?

Tags: python, r, spotfire

Is there a way to use a Python script to launch multiple R scripts, from say a button from within? (I'm thinking of having a button on a visualization page)

Let's say that I have `[R Script One]` and `[R Script Two]`, that I want to run them both, one after the other. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [executing an R script from python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688177/executing-an-r-script-from-python)

Comment: @letsc Not in this instance: This is when you try to use Python as a scripting language -- think VBA macros in Excel -- to do stuff in an application called Spotfire. What I'm trying to do here is call an R script using Python "macros" in the Spotfire application.