# Simple way to pass directory to r script using python

Tags: python, r

I have tried using `rpy2` in order to generate plots within a python script before, but now I am doing a bit more complicated things within R scripts. Using python I am outputting a number of datafiles, and my R scripts only need the directory and file name to analyze.

Is there an easy way in python to call an r script and pass it directory and filename?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the Python [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) library and [RScript](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rscript)

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['Rscript.exe', 'script.r', 'filename'])
```